# Pandas Dataframe to dictionary groupby index

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, dataframe

I have a dataframe with 3 columns, all of them have string values. The dataframe is of this form:

```
Key Word    Synonym    Alternatives
   A          word1         NaN
   A          word2         NaN
   A          word3         word11
   B          word4         word12
   B          word5         NaN 
   B          word6         word13
   C          word7         word14
   C          word8         NaN
   C          word9         NaN
   D          word10        word15
```

What I want, is to convert it to a dictionary, which will be grouped based on the `Key Word` column, and for every key_word, to return all the corresponding synonyms and alternative synonyms. So, all the values of `A` will be referring to the corresponding values that exist in the `Synonym` and `Alternatives` for `A` etc. Is there a way to do this? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you need [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) for drop `NaN`s and then [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with `list`. Last call [`to_dict`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.to_dict.html):

```
d = df.set_index('Key').stack().groupby('Key').apply(list).to_dict()
print (d)
{'B': ['word4', 'word12', 'word5', 'word6', 'word13'], 
 'D': ['word10', 'word15'], 
 'C': ['word7', 'word14', 'word8', 'word9'], 
 'A': ['word1', 'word2', 'word3', 'word11']}
```

Comment: Elegant! `{i: x.values.tolist() for i, x in df.set_index('Key').stack().groupby('Key')}` is very'l marginally fast for larger dataframes, not worth the gain.